# Picasso errors on callback

Tags: android, picasso

I've noticed that occasionally images won't load in my app through picasso and that picasso is in fact erring. I am using two images per list item in a list view. Here's the picasso code:

```
Picasso.with(DashboardActivity.this).load(status).into(iv_customer_status_pic, new Callback() {
              @Override public void onSuccess() {
                  Log.d("Debug", "Picasso Success");
              }

              @Override public void onError() {
                  Log.d("Debug", "Picasso Errored");
              }
            });
```

How can I ensure that the images are loaded, I don't want them to error and then make them disappear. Also why does it error? Is there a timeout? I noticed on more powerful devices it happens less.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `onError()` callback for `Picasso.with().load().into(target, callback)` exists is because there is no 100% guarantee the load will be successful.  For example if you are trying to load from a uri and you don't have an internet connection, the load will not be successful.
You can somehow attempt a re-try (which I think is already built into Picasso), but ultimately, you need to handle the case were the load fails (for whatever reason). One option would be to load a "default" image, like a generic "profile picture" if you were trying to load a specific users profile picture.

If you move the implementation of the callbacks to a separate class , or even the containing class you should be able to retry from the `onError()` call back.  Here is what I am thinking:

```
class ContainingClass implements Callback.EmptyCallback

private int mRetryAttempts = 0;

@Override
public void onError() {
    if (mRetryAttempts < 2) {
        mRetryAttempts++;
        // try again
    } else {
        mRetryAttempts = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    mRetryAttempts = 0;
}
```

Comment: In my case I need the image to load, so a retry would make sense. Is there a way to increase the number of retires? According to their site it does 3 attempts before an error callback

Comment: I took a quick look and did not see anyway, but part of my point above was you should be able to use the onError call back to do a re-try .. I will add a suggested way to my answer

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why it fails might because of no Internet connection and Invalid Image URL. 
With regard to the error handling refer to nPn's answer.

Comment: it's more of a comment not an answer

Comment: sorry, it's because i cannot comment on other's post because of my low reputation.